# My PrepareInterceptor is being executed many times with null fields

Tags: java, interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to use my PrepareInterceptor to see if my B2BUnit is receiving addresses, if not I want to set the B2BUnit as not active.

This is my code;

```
@Override
public void onPrepare(final B2BUnitModel model, final InterceptorContext ctx) throws InterceptorException
{

    if (!haveMandatoryFields(model))
    {
        if (!ctx.isNew(model) && ctx.isModified(model, B2BUnitModel.ACTIVE) && model.getActive() == true)
        {
            throw new InterceptorException(InterceptorsErrorMessages.B2BUnit.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
        }
        else
        {
            model.setActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having two problems here.

1. I'm adding just one B2BUnit with 1 address and the PrepareInterceptor is being executed 3 times...
2. Each execution come with new fields, and I need them all on the first one. The 'model.getAddresses()' are null until 3rd execution and my interceptorContext.getDirtyAttributes(model) is bringing all my B2BUnit fields except for `addresses` at 1st execution, `readableCatalogVersions` at 2nd one, and `readableCatalogVersions` again with `addresses` at 3st one.

Comment: make a condition on null and check there might be possibility in code before setting address to b2bunit it's getting saved.

Comment: @RaushanKumar I think there should be a transparent way to solve this. Adding some conditions will make very messy the code :/